# Restrict Asp:TextBox to not allow more than 6 character in it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to restrict the user that he cant enter more than 6 characters in a text box.As a user start entering in the text box and reach to the max limit and try entering 7th character, the text box will not allow him to do so and alert him that max size reached.How i achieve this?

I had added JavaScript function in my code to do so but not getting that on which event i call this function , currently i am calling on on-blur but i m able to type more than 9 character in the text box and after that when i m clicking on a button then i m getting alert message.i want that while typing in the text box itself if max limit reached the user get prompted.My Current code is as follow:-

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtVolumeProcessed" runat="server" CssClass="text" MaxLength="999999" onblur="javascript:validate();"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

and the Javascript Code is:-

```
function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('<%=txtVolumeProcessed.ClientID%>').value.length > 7) {
        alert("Volume Processed not exceed 999999");
        document.getElementById('<%=txtVolumeProcessed.ClientID%>').select();
        document.getElementById('<%=txtVolumeProcessed.ClientID%>').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an asp.net textbox, you can set the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx) property on it.  This will accomplish what you're looking for.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: As you see in my code, i had already mentioned it but still i can enter more than 6 character in the textbox.

Comment: You're setting maxLength to 999999 - try setting it to 6

Comment: Thanks ,I had never used this property preveously so i make like this but you pointed my mistake and now i ll never do such mistake again while using this property.

Comment: Awesome - glad to hear it.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

MaxLength Property will Gets or sets the maximum number of characters the user can type or paste into the text box control.

If you write `6` then Six characters you can type in.

So change `999999` to `6`.

Answer (score 0):

give value of property `MaxLength` to `6` if want to user entered only `6` characters `insted of 999999`.

```
No need to check by java script because in `asp:textbox` gives the property to set max.  characters entered by user.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ASP.NET Core**, this little bit of JQuery did the trick for me (Might work in regular ASP.NET as well, but that was not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[data-val-length-max]").each(function(index) {
    // console.log( index + ": " + $(this).attr('data-val-length-max'));
    $(this).attr("maxlength", $(this).attr('data-val-length-max'));
  });
});
```

Use the above code in combination with validation attributes from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations like MaxLengthAttribute and/or StringLengthAttribute as such:

> [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "The middle initial value cannot exceed 1 character.")]
>
> [MaxLength(1, ErrorMessage = "The middle initial value cannot exceed 1 character.")]

You may also use additional validation attributes, as needed.  For example, I use a regular expression to validate the middle initial as well:

> [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z']*$", ErrorMessage = "Only alpha characters are allowed.")]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's using the default TextMode; if you try something like **Numbe* MaxLength is ignored.